# SQL Server 2000 Reverse Engineer Tool

Tags: sql-server, reverse-engineering

Is there any free tool that I can use to reverse engineer databases in SQL server 2000? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx

Or you can write a script

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_DB_DOCUMENTATION.aspx

Although your question would probably get better answers on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 1):

Visio can do it (effectively free in your shop, perhaps)

Or open it in SSMS and create a database diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my tools [dbscript](http://www.devio.at/index.php/dbscript) and [SMOscript](http://www.devio.at/index.php/smoscript)